# Loading symbols python loop

Tags: python, python-3.6

In python 2 i have this simple loop

```
while True:
    for i in ["/", "-", "|", "\\", "|"]:
        print "%s\r" % i,
```

It produces a loop of those symbols, on the same line, replacing each character in place (so you never see more than 1 symbol)

However, in python3

```
while True:
    for i in ["/", "-", "|", "\\", "|"]:
        print("%s\r" % i,)
```

The same code, when fixed for syntax, prints each symbol on a new line

Not sure what I am missing, would appreciate the help

Comment: Each `print` statement in Python 3 produces a new line. That behavior is to be expected.

Comment: Summing up the duplicate: the syntax to print without a newline in Python 2 is a trailing comma on the `print` statement, but the argument in Python 3 is `end`: `print("%s\r" % i, end="")`.